# Propagation error for a third grade equation

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis, experimental-technique

I am trying to find the value for the roots$\pm$error for a set of experimental data. The function that fit the best is $$\epsilon(t)=a+bt+ct^2+dt^3.$$

**Which is the best way to calculate the roots $\epsilon(t)=0$ and its errors?**  I usually use the variance formula:

[image: Variance formula]

As I can't find $t(\epsilon)$, the only way that came to mind is using the known expressions for the solutions of the third grade and compute the unpleasant set of propagations of the errors but I'm sure that there isa simpler and more efficient way to do it and in fact, I would like to find a general method, for example if it was the case $\epsilon(t)=4t^2+e^{-t^2}$.

Comment: Although there may be some physics experiment behind this question, it is really about mathematics isn't it, not physics?  You might get a more informed answer at Mathematics SE.

Comment: Well, I consider it quite close to the methods we are used to see in the physics experiments.

Comment: A mathematician is likely to give a better answer.  I doubt many physicists come across such a problem.  But it is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

If your curve-fitting program allows it, instead of fitting $y=a+bt+ct^2+dt^3$ you could try fitting $y=d(t-a)(t-b)(t-c)$. The output parameters $a$, $b$, $c$ will then be the required roots and the errors (or rather variances and/or co-variances) will be included in the statistics.

Comment: I really liked that option! It's quite clever! I am using GNUPlot and I have tried but: it is incapable of fitting the data using that expression. I don't understand.

Comment: @MarcC: Remove any constant offset first, then try the fitting process again.

Comment: @MarcC : gnuplot isn't a dedicated curve-fitting program, but I don't know of any of other curve-fitting program which does offer that much flexibility.  There are numerical solvers which can find the roots, but as for the errors...